# How can I determine if an app session was closed by an error?

Tags: r, session, shiny

I'd like to know if last Shiny application session was closed by error, not by user. I tried to use `session$onSessionEnded()` but it executes on error too. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: You should use `trycatch` with some sort of logging, by printing errors to a text file as much as you can within your app

Comment: I know, but I'm looking for more general solution.

Comment: @Taz Did you find a solution to this in the last 2.5 years? I'm struggling with the same thing now.

Comment: @bobbel unfortunately I haven't figured it out, but made some workaround script https://gist.github.com/Tazovsky/8b18acc10dff5d58c76dcb7529081900 which is run periodically on Jenkins.

Comment: @Taz Thanks, but it doesn't solve my problem unfortunately. I'll keep on searching I guess.

Comment: @bobbel OK, keep me posted, please :)